# Automated SSL or expedited ssl not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https, cname

I have an app on Heroku with DNS mapped to godaddy domain. I have the setup for godaddy as `CNAME   www www.myapp.com.herokudns.com`

So if I go to http://www.myapp.com it works.

I am trying to add ssl so I can use https://www.myapp.com instead. I tried upgrading my app to hobby as shown here: https://blog.heroku.com/announcing-automated-certificate-management but it doesn't work. If I go to https://myapp.com it takes a long time while connecting and then gives me an error: `This site can't be reached` .

I also tried expedited ssl on heroku but that didn't work either. How should I setup SSL on my app so the godaddy domain can be accessed over https

When I added config.force_ssl = true in production.rb, the app didnt work at all.

note: myapp is the placeholder name of the original app

Comment: heroku certs:auto shows status ok. But I can't access the app through https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. I didn't add an SSL certificate although I added the automatic certificate management. Finally, figured it out, added expeditedSSL on Heroku and retried again. Everything works now.

Added `config.force_ssl = true` in rails `config/environments/production` as well